# What do you call this type of person?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call someone who is seemingly working with you but is actually working against you?

Comment: Look up synonyms of [traitor](http://thesaurus.com/browse/traitor).

Comment: Since you seem like an English learner, [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) would be a good place for you to post your questions. You can also meet lot of other English language learners there. This site is primarily meant for English language experts, linguists and such. Hope to see more of you here or at [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)!

Comment: Young people would call that person [a frenemy.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frenemy) (I was surprised to find the word in the Merriam-Webster Dictionary.)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the situation **backstabber** may be an appropriate word. For example, someone may ask the advice of a friend regarding a love interest whilst that same friend has ideas of his/her own regarding the same person. The friend may seem to give good advice but is in fact trying to make the situation better for him/herself.

Answer (score -1):

I would call that person **[dead weight](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dead+weight)**.